# Glob watch multiple files, process one

Tags: gulp, gulp-sass, gulp-dest

I use [Gulp 4](https://gulpjs.com/) with [gulp-sass](https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-sass). What I try to do is the following.

- The code I provide here is just a fragment of the whole code, to show the important parts.
- The `watch` should like it does, watch all `.scss` files.
- In `style()`, only the current file is going to be processed.
- If I save `custom/components/header/header.scss`, then only `custom/components/header/header.scss` should be processed, not all files.
- The saved file should then have a filename like `assets/css/dist/header/header.css`
- Both `src` and `dest` is unknown in this case because I don't have a single file to grab on to.
- I see now that I also need to remove `custom/components` from the `dest`, but the important thing is that I can get the current file to start working with that.

```
gulp.watch('custom/components/**/*.scss', style);
```

```php
function style() {
  return gulp
    .src()
    .pipe(sass())
    .on('error', sass.logError)
    .pipe(gulp.dest('assets/css/dist'));
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just figure it out. It's possible to do it like this.

```
let watcher = gulp.watch(css.watch);

watcher.on('change', function(path) {
  console.log(path);
  style();
}
```